# Keeping variable values when the iPhone is shut-down?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Lets say i have an application which has three text-fields, and i can type whatever i want into them, lets also assume that i have a checkbox and a button. And if the button is tapped while the checkbox is checked, the nsstring values in these textfields should get saved somehow. Lets say i power down my iPhone and restarted it, opened the app once again and wanted those values to be in their respective textfields.

How does one do this?

Is this a case for NSUserDefaults or something for Apple's own Keychain API to handle?

Cheers.

**Edit:** We used local declarations when setting and getting the values of the NSUserDefaults, which of course, doesnt work. It works perfectly now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can make use of [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @7KV7 Ok, we've tried using NSUserDefaults, but the variables only seem to keep themselves alive to the same extent that the iPhone is alive. As soon as we power down the simulator or the iPhone, the variables dissapears.

Comment: As far as I know user defaults is removed only when the application is uninstalled or removed from the device. How did u set it.

Comment: Can you power down the simulator? Just curious to know. How do u do that?

Comment: That quits the simulator.. User defaults will not be removed by that. I have used it many times

Comment: We initiate our nsuserdefaults only on the actual button-tap, and no other place. i've seen others using the appdelegate methods, but it's nothing we've tried yet.

We also only load the nsuserdefaults on viewdidappear, which i've come to sense now, might not be the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate a sqlite3 database into ur app.. save the textfields value in an array and sav it in the database. On starting of the apps just load from the database and retrieve the top most array and show the values back as output.. Hope it helps.. I am new also.. but cant think of anything else if u want to restart ur whole phone and still wants the fields to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSUserDefaults` for stuff that doesn't need to be stored securely and Keychain if it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSUserDefaults or a PList or a database to save the content. 
Example is given below:-

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Jayahari" forKey:@"userName"];
```

PList can be used for archiving, serilizing. Database also can be used for same purpose.